# Query SQLite database with similar entries

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, fts3

I have to query an `fts3` table inside an android application. The idea is to query the db every time I type something inside a `SearchView`.

The **table** is composed by **one column** that looks like that:

```
go go
go up
go down
```

If i use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column MATCH 'go g*'
```

I get all three rows as result but I want just the row "***go go***" in return.

Is there a way to do that? I though about eliminating the spaces, since they seem to be the issue but I wanted to know, if there is a more straight forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'go g%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joao! It does work! Is there a way to keep using MATCH? My end project uses a big db and I am concerned about LIKE being slow.

Comment: I have never used MATCH so I can't help you on that. But I never had any problems with LIKE.

Comment: But try this, nevertheless, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column MATCH 'go g'`

Comment: Thanks again, without "*" does not work for me. As i mentioned the query happens every time I type something, even incomplete words.

Comment: Then I think the best solution for you is to use LIKE

Comment: I haven't tried this but it may be that `MATCH '"go* g*"'` would work as per *Phrase queries. A phrase query is a query that retrieves all documents that contain a nominated set of terms or term prefixes in a specified order with no intervening tokens. Phrase queries are specified by enclosing a space separated sequence of terms or term prefixes in double quotes (").* [SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions  - Phrase queries](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html)

Comment: Here we go! Thank you very much Mike! It works as I want using MATCH